# Identifier expected java

Tags: java, methods, average, identifier

I keep getting a compiler error that states an identifier is expected where the code says public static String Mainmenu (menu);. I am new to programming so I know it is probably something simple. The code uses methods and when all is compiled correctly it should run as a grade averaging program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework4 {

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    int choice;
    String name;
    String menu1;
    double homeworkAverage = 0.0;
    double quizAverage = 0.0;
    double testAverage = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    double totalAverage = 0.0;

    do{

        menu1 = Mainmenu;

        choice = input.nextInt();

        if( choice == 1 )
        {

            System.out.println( "Eneter the student's name:");

                name = input.next();

            System.out.println( "Enter homework grades");

                homeworkAverage = mean();

            System.out.println( "Enter Quiz Grades");

                quizAverage = mean();

            System.out.println( "Enter Test Grades");

                testAverage = mean();

            totalAverage = 0.25*homeworkAverage + 0.25*quizAverage +0.5*testAverage;

            System.out.println( "The average for " + name + " is: " + totalAverage );

            }
            else if ( choice == 2 )
            {
                System.out.println( "Now quiting...");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "Invalid Choice" );
            }


    }while( choice != 2 );
}


public static String Mainmenu ( menu );
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    String menu;


        System.out.println("Welcome to Grader 1.0");
        System.out.println("1. Average a New Student");
        System.out.println("2. Quit");
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Choice:");


        return menu;

}



public static double mean(double average );
{

Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

double grade = 0.0; 
double average = 0.0;
double gradeTotal = 0.0;
int numberOfGrades = 0;

while( grade != -1 )
{

    System.out.println( "Please enter the next grade or -1 when finished: "); 
    grade = input.nextDouble ();

    if( grade != -1 )
    {
        gradeTotal = gradeTotal + grade;
        numberOfGrades++;
    }

}
    if( numberOfGrades > 0 )
        {

        average = gradeTotal / numberOfGrades;

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No grades, no average");
        }   

            return average; 


}
}
```

Comment: Just one hint: Don't start a method name with capital letter like `Mainmenu(...)`, always start with small letter followed by word(s) starting with capital letter, `mainMenu(menu),..`. This is not a rule and not making any error, but it's standard.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `;` after `public static String Mainmenu ( menu );`

Same for the `;` operator after `public static double mean(double average );`

The problem is you're trying to define methods, while the `;` operator means *end of statement*. And since you're terminating after the method signatures, those methods are not provided with body blocks.

Note that you're allowed to add `;` after a method's body, **but not between the method signature and the body**. For example,

```
public void myMethod() {
  //body
};
```

Answer (score 0):

//Hi There, my opinion is that you should structure the main better with control switches calling the specific methods. Something like:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework4{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int menu = 0; //initial menu selection
    int menuChoice = 0; //user menu selection
    double meanValue = 0; //Mean value

    menuChoice = MainMenu(menu); //user return menu choice              
    switch (menuChoice) {
        case 1:  FindMean(meanValue);
            break;
        case 2:  Exit();
                break;
        default:  errorMsg();
            break;
    }       
}



//MminMenu
public static int MainMenu(int menu){
    System.out.println("Welcome to Grader 1.0");
            System.out.println("1. Average a New Student");
            System.out.println("2. Quit");
    System.out.print("Select: ");

    //user selection
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    menu = input.nextInt();

    return menu;    
} 


//FindMean
public static final void FindMean(double mean) {
    //write method for FindMean

} 

    //Exit
public static final void Exit() {
    //write method for Exit

} 



// Error
public static final void errorMsg() {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry on the indentation not aligned well xD